# How to automatically convert my Custom javascript file to minified version

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom javascript file for my project. But I have read that we should always use minified version because it's efficient. So everytime I make a change in my Custom.js file, I go to online tool convert my New custom.js file and delete my old Minified Custom JS file from my project and replace it with new one(minified one). Is there any good way to handle this situation.  Kindly note that in no where in my project I am referring to the actual Custom.Js file. I have added only the reference to the Minified version.

IDE: Visual Studio Community Edition Free 
(2017)

Comment: The default is to use the inbuilt [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) features of the framework. It will use your un-minified version in debug mode, and automatically minify it in production mode

Comment: I know about bundling, as I can see the bundles for Jquery and all in BundleConfig.cs. I did not know about Minification. I will look into it now. So, I am assuming it will automatically detect that there is some change in mY Custom Js file and will update the Min file automatically

Comment: Yes. In production, your js and css files will be automatically minified and cached for 12 months. If you make a change to your file, it will be cleared and minified and cached again

Comment: That's awesome, So, I do not need to use https://gruntjs.com/  tool. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sir, when you say cached, you mean server cache, or the client cache. You mean the IIS will cache, or it will be cached to the all the website visitor's browser who will visit the website from next time.

Comment: Client side. But using grunt (and npm and bower) is also an option to bundle and minify (and is being recommended for core-mvc). Refer [this article](http://www.jeffreyfritz.com/2015/05/where-did-my-asp-net-bundles-go-in-asp-net-5/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154090/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-unbreakable).

Answer (score 0):

Bundling and Minification is a default feature from MVC4. you just need to be implement in your bundle config file.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Detailed document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification). please follow.

Answer (score -1):

You can try use a plugin for your IDE :)

Then you save your file it will automaticaly save one .min its possible for CSS too. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I didn't because I don't have enought reputation :/

Comment: I  mean to say, I have added the information you asked, in the edit section of my question. :) (Scroll up and see my question).